# Photoshop not opening (hardware or system error)

Tags: error-handling, photoshop

Previously the photoshop is working on 12.04 ubuntu OS but now the photoshop is saying

```
Unable to continue because of a hardware or system error. 
Sorry, but this error is unrecoverable.
```

I reinstall photoshop with no luck
So how can I open photoshop again?

Comment: http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9623 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final solution:

https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-users/2008-July/038454.html

It is a permanent fix, you do not need to do it every time you start Photoshop.

(Here is a [mirror](http://pastebin.com/jhbrwxKk))

Answer (score 1):

I made work photoshop work by updating `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`.
Actually the solution was found from Rinzwind's comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, hold down all three Ctrl+Alt+Shift buttons
2. Now "while keeping those button held," simply open Photoshop or a file that opens with Photoshop
3. As Photoshop loads, you should get a prompt asking if you would like to "delete the Photoshop settings file", Click yes

You should now be able to start Photoshop and the error message should disappear.
But remember that you have to do this step each time to start photoshop.